# App Manifest File Error when generating bundle files

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, manifest

I am getting following errors when creating appx bundle file in release mode

1)

> error 80080204: All app package manifests in a bundle must declare the
>   same values under the XPath
>   *[local-name()='Package']/*[local-name()='Dependencies']. The values under this XPath declared in the manifest for the package with file
>   name

2)

> The specified package format is not valid: The package manifest is not
>   valid.

Can I get the reason I am facing the above issues as previously my files got created without errors. 
Is there any changes do I need to do in the configuration Manager for the release?

Comment: Please compare x86 x64 app's **build** setting page. If they are different will cause this issue.

Comment: I have two projects inside one solution, for both the projects I have selected Release and Platform as Any CPU in build configuration, and in project properties, i have selected platform target as x86 and selected Compile with .NET tool chain checkbox.

I am still facing the same issue.
My app is currently published in Microsoft Store and i am trying to create a bundle file for the next version with same package name.

Comment: Please try delete all the bin bundleAtifacts appx file and obj folder then create again and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

That error is misleading
I managed to solve this by changing the csproj file

```
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
```

I also made sure that `TRACE;DEBUG` was removed from the `<DefineConstants>`

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error when i forgot to change the Configuration from Debug to Release.
I changed and it is resolved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35831664)